# Installing Language Tool in TexStudio under OSX

Tags: languages, texstudio, mac

I have installed LT in TexStudio in my tablet who runs win7.

But I could not realise this under OSX. I don't know why. Is there any body doing this under OSX? Or, is there any useful link like this one: http://wiki.languagetool.org/checking-la-tex-with-languagetool

PS: if i type http(slash,slash)localhost :8081 in my browser, I got a error like this:
[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a non-issue.